# Секция из 2-х background + прозрачный фон

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Приветствую. Есть у меня секция у которой 1 картинка не прозрачная(http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1701/57/04977bc315b6.jpg) + еще 1 прозрачная(http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1701/f6/b574a41380c1.png) и полупрозрачный фон(background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);). При добавлении контента блок **search_wrapper** не растягивается автоматически в высоту.

Секция сделана по принципу hover эффекта при наведении к примеру на блок с картинкой.

Я нуждаюсь в помощи потому что сам уже не знаю как поступить. Я уже всё перепробовал что мог =)
Прикладываю код ниже  [+  код с песочницы для удобства:](https://jsfiddle.net/tyL7cp8f/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-height: 449px;
  background-image: url(http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1701/57/04977bc315b6.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.search_wrapper {
  padding-top: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-image: url(http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1701/f6/b574a41380c1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
.search_title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.15);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.search_form {
  max-width: 472px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.search_cover {
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
.search_box {
  width: 222px;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
.search_entry {
  width: 472px;
  height: 57px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.search_button {
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 19px 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c1412e;
  background-color: #e94e38;
  margin-top: 28px;
}
.search_link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.15);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
.search_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.style {
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.style:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1E90FF;
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 550px) {
 .search_entry, .search_box{
  width: 100%;
 }
 
.inline{
  display: block;
 }
.search_cover{
 margin-right: 0px; 
 }

 
}
```

```html
<section class="search">
 <div class="search_wrapper">
  <h1 class="search_title">What are you looking for?</h1>
  <form class="search_form" action="">
   <div class="search_cover inline">
    <select name="" id="" class="search_box style">
     <option value="1">Dubai</option>
     <option value="2">Dubai</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="search_cover  one inline">
    <select name="" id="" class="search_box style">
     <option value="1">Education</option>
     <option value="2">Education</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="search_envelop">
    <input class="search_entry style" type="text" placeholder="Keyword, name, date, ...">
   </div>
   <div class="search_button">
    <a href="/" class="search_link">
     Search
    </a>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вынесете содержимое за пределы .search_wrapper и добавьте им z-index.

Получается что вы тянете абсолютно спозиционированный блок, который никак не влияет на размеры родительского блока и не тянет его.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-height: 449px;
  background-image: url(http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1701/57/04977bc315b6.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 58px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.search_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-image: url(http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1701/f6/b574a41380c1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
.search_title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.15);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;

  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
form {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.search_form {
  max-width: 472px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.search_cover {
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
.search_box {
  width: 222px;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
.search_entry {
  width: 472px;
  height: 57px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.search_button {
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 19px 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c1412e;
  background-color: #e94e38;
  margin-top: 28px;
}
.search_link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.15);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
.search_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.style {
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.style:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1E90FF;
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 550px) {
 .search_entry, .search_box{
  width: 100%;
 }
 
.inline{
  display: block;
 }
.search_cover{
 margin-right: 0px; 
 }

 
}
```

```html
<section class="search">
 <div class="search_wrapper"></div>
    <h1 class="search_title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h1>
  <form class="search_form" action="">
   <div class="search_cover inline">
    <select name="" id="" class="search_box style">
     <option value="1">Dubai</option>
     <option value="2">Dubai</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="search_cover  one inline">
    <select name="" id="" class="search_box style">
     <option value="1">Education</option>
     <option value="2">Education</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="search_envelop">
    <input class="search_entry style" type="text" placeholder="Keyword, name, date, ...">
   </div>
   <div class="search_button">
    <a href="/" class="search_link">
     Search
    </a>
   </div>
  </form>
</section>
```